Understanding the Equation for Unit Vectors in Curvilinear Coordinate Systems
I am trying to understand the derivation of divergence in curvilinear coordinate systems. I stumbled upon this equation and it seems enigmatic to me. I know that $\mathbf{e}_{u_i}$ are the unit vectors of the curvilinear system and $h_{u_i}$ are the corresponding lengths. The Nabla operator is also clear. Can somebody explain where this equation comes from? Presumably, my confusion is rooted in not knowing what $ u_i $ means.
$$ \mathbf{e}_{u_i} = h_{u_i} \cdot \nabla u_i $$

Let $p(u^i)$ be the function taking coordinates $u^1,\dotsc,u^n$ to points. Then the holonomic basis for this coordinate system is
$$
  e_i = \frac{\partial p}{\partial u^i}.
\tag{$*$}
$$
For any basis we can define a reciprocal basis $e^i$ via
$$
  e^i\cdot e_j = \delta^i_j.
$$
For any vector $v$ it is easy to compute from this definition that
$$
  v = \sum_i(v\cdot e_i)e^i = \sum_i(v\cdot e^i)e_i.
$$
Now recall that $v\cdot\nabla$ is the $v$-directional derivative operator. Then it ought to be that $e_j\cdot\nabla u^i = 0$ when $i\ne j$ since $e_j$ represents exactly the direction in which only $u^i$ varies and in which $u^j$ is constant. (Think about ($*$) and the definition of partial derivative.) In particular $e_i\cdot\nabla = \partial/\partial u^i$, and this makes it clear that $e_i\cdot\nabla u^i = 1$. But this means that
$$
  e^i = \nabla u^i.
$$
Now it is trivial that
$$
  \nabla = \sum_ie^i(e_i\cdot\nabla) = \sum_ie^i\frac\partial{\partial u^i}.
$$

The coordinates $u^i$ are orthogonal if the basis $e_i$ is orthogonal. In this case it is easy to see that the reciprocal basis $e^i$ is orthogonal, and in fact
$$
  e^i = \frac1{|e_i|^2}e_i.
$$
Let $h_i = |e_i|$. Then in terms of the orthonormal basis $\hat e_i = e_i/h_i = h_ie^i$ we see immediately that
$$
  \nabla = \sum_i\frac1{h_i}\hat e_i\frac\partial{\partial x^i}.
$$
We also get the equation
$$
  \hat e_i = h_ie^i = h_i\nabla u^i.
$$

Thank you very much!
